# How to make pycharm open files without replacing currently open file?

Tags: pycharm

I am using pychram.
Every time i try to open some new file, instead of opening it
along to previous opened file.

How can i make pycharm open the source file on different tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have the tabs enabled (Editor | General | Editor Tabs | Tab Appearance | Placement).